# Copy the data from one range to another sheet range

Tags: vba, excel, spreadsheet

Q: I would like to copy some 2 column of data to another sheet of particular range. Please help with this. Thanks in advance.

```
Sub cutpaste()
    Range("c5:d7").Cut Sheets("C:\Users\Sai\Desktop\Anil peddi\Practice.xlsm\sheet2")range("f5")
End Sub
```

Comment: - 1 Seriously???? Why was this question up voted? Sometimes I doubt the sanity of the people who upvote and downvote :/ @Anil: You need to ask meaningful questions. Like What problems are you facing? What is not working as expected? Are you getting any error messages? etc etc...

Comment: @siddharth: I am learning basic VBA programs and i was trying to copy the data from one sheet to another using copy and paste methods. Can you tell me what meaningful questions i have to ask?. If you are not in a position to answer to my small question, why you are raising a voice over me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub myMacro()

    ' source
    Dim wbkSour As Workbook
        Set wbkSour = Workbooks("WorkBookNameWhereMacroIs.xlsm")

    ' destination
    Dim wbkDest As Workbook
        Set wbkDest = Workbooks.Open("C:\...\DestinationWorkBookName.xlsm")

    ' copying proccess
    wbkDest.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F5:G7").Value = wbkSour.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C5:D7").Value

    ' save and close destination
    wbkDest.Save
    wbkDest.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: can't we do with copy and paste methods?

Comment: You could, but why do you want to do it that way?

Comment: i thought it would be easier rather than above code.